# ASP.NET Core route with constraint is not falling back to default route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have a new ASP.NET Core web application with routing defined as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "sitemap",
        defaults: new { controller = "Sitemap", action = "Index" },
        template: "sitemap.xml");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "cms",
        template: "{*permalink}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new { permalink = new CmsRouteConstraint() });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

When I request the URL `/` I see my home page served by `HomeController`. When I request the URL `/sitemap.xml` I see the XML served by `SitemapController`. When I request a URL for which my `Match` method in `CmsRouteConstraint` returns `true` I see the request being handled by `ContentController`.

However, all other URLs are returning a 404 response. By my understanding these URLs should still be handled by my default route and passed to `HomeController` but they're not. What I find strange is that regardless of whether I request URL `/` or `/where/am/i` I can see `CmsRouteConstraint` returning `false` both times, so why would the former end up being handled by `HomeController` and not the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use what you have. For exaple if you want call `/yolo/swag` it will be handled by `deafult` route but you dont have `yolo` controller with `swag` action and will return 404

Also remember about `*` in `cms` route and his catch-all route function so i reccoment use "greedy matching" at the end of route table

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand your point. /yolo/swag would be handled by default route which specifies Home as default controller and Index as default action. So should be passed to HomeController, not 404. And re. greedy matching, the plan is for that route to catch all requests, check a condition which, if false, passes request to next route in route table. There are cases where I want the 404 response but right now I need to understand why '/' goes through HomeController but 'anything/else' doesn't.

Comment: @TomTroughton Troughton You dont understand how routing in ASP.NET Core MVC working. `{controller=Home}` means take controller or if is empty set deafult `Home`. `/yolo/swag` will use `yolo` controller, not deafult `Home` (but using `deafult` route name)

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for explaining.